# Telethon find .session file phone number

Tags: python, session, telethon, pyrogram

I have already authorized .session file I forgot his number,
tried adding other account to contact,
tried changing privacy so I can see from other accs,
all with no success..
any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log in to the Telethon .session file normally and get the current user of the session:

```
user = await client.get_entity("me")
print(user.phone)
```